# How to change the width of a floating pallete in DM scripting

Tags: dm-script

Now I'm trying to write a DM script to display a floating palette as shown in the following code. However, for example, a long string label as included in this code protrude from the palette window. So, I'm wondering how to change the palette window size (i.e, width in this case). Actually, some Gatan's official palette windows such as "Camera View", "Camera Acquire" etc. seem to be wider than the pallete created by this code. It will be appreciated if you share some wisdom. Thank you very much in advance.

```
Class MyDialog: UIFrame
{
    TagGroup createDLGtgs( Object self ){
        TagGroup DLGtgs, DLGItems
        DLGtgs = DLGCreateDialog( "Test Dialog", DLGItems )
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( "Test of Gatan DigitalMicrograph scripting" ) )
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreatePushButton( "OK", "testOK" ) )
        return DLGtgs
    }
//
    Object Init( Object self ){
        self.super.Init( self.createDLGtgs() )
        return self
    }
//
    Void testOK( Object self ){
        OKDialog( "Hello!" )
    }
}
//
Object DialogOBJ = Alloc( MyDialog ).Init()
String DialogName = "Test Dialog"
String toolName = "Test Tool"
RegisterScriptPalette( DialogOBJ, DialogName, toolName )
OpenGadgetPanel(toolName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Be aware that **the situation of floating palettes is different between `GMS 2.x` and `GMS 3.x`**.
> Essentially, registered floating palettes are phased out in `GMS 3.x` with the new UI. They are still supported to some extend, but not all functionality remains and some behavior is buggy. For `GMS 3.x` it is generally better to launch scripted dialogs as *modal* or *modeless* dialogs and no longer install them as *palettes*.

---

### This answer here is for `GMS 2.x` (Tested with GMS 2.3.3)

You need to add *position tags* to the dialog-describing tagGroup. You do this in your example code of the question above by adding to the `TagGroup createDLGtgs( Object self )` method:

```
TagGroup positionTgs = DLGBuildPositionFromApplication()
positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "Width", "Medium" ) 
DLGtgs.DLGPosition( positionTgs )
```

The string values accepted are:

- `"Small"` Like the left-hand tool palettes of GMS 2.x.
- `"Medium"` Like the right-hand tool palettes of GMS 2.x
- `"Wide"` extra wide

There are, however, a few addtional options for the *position* tags, but they will not apply to floating palettes, just to regular *modeless dialogs*. You can set the width and height of a window either with an *absolute size* value or let it be *automatically determined* by the size of the content. Here is an example:

```
class CMyClass : UIFrame
{
    void InitAndShow( object self ) {
        Taggroup DLG,DLGItems
        DLG = DLGCreateDialog("Test",DLGItems)
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( "Just some long text for extra width" ))
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( "A second line" ))
        
        TagGroup positionTgs = DLGBuildPositionFromApplication()
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "Width", DLGBuildAutoSize() )
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "Height", DLGBuildAbsoluteSize( 45, "pixel" ) )
        DLG.DLGPosition( positionTgs )
    
        self.super.Init( DLG ).Display("Test")
    }
}

Alloc(CMyClass).InitAndShow()
```

In the above `DLGBuildPositionFromApplication()` sets the application window as the reference frame for the dialog. One can then define the position of the dialog left|center|right and top|center|bottom to that frame using the command `DLGBuildRelativePosition()` with `-1|0|1` as respective parameter, like in the example:

```
class CMyClass : UIFrame
{
    void InitAndShow( object self ) {
        Taggroup DLG,DLGItems
        DLG = DLGCreateDialog("Test",DLGItems)
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( "Just some long text for extra width" ))
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( "A second line" ))
        
        TagGroup positionTgs = DLGBuildPositionFromApplication()
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "Width", DLGBuildAutoSize() )
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "Height", DLGBuildAutoSize() )
        
        // Appear top-right     
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "X", DLGBuildRelativePosition( "Inside", 1 ) )
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "Y", DLGBuildRelativePosition( "Inside", -1 ) )
        DLG.DLGPosition( positionTgs )
        
        self.super.Init( DLG ).Display("Test")
    }
}

Alloc(CMyClass).InitAndShow()
```

The reference-frame does not have to be the application window, though. You can specify any wanted using `DLGBuildPosition()`, which allows using f.e. a window rect and then placing the dialog right of it. And with the reference-frame, one can also size the dialog window relative to that using `DLGBuildMatchSize()` as in the following example:

```
class CMyClass : UIFrame
{
    void InitAndShow( object self, documentWindow win ) {
        Taggroup DLG,DLGItems
        DLG = DLGCreateDialog("Test",DLGItems)
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( "Just some long text for extra width" ))
        DLGItems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( "A second line" ))
        
        number t,l,b,r
        win.WindowGetFrameBounds(t,l,b,r)
        TagGroup positionTgs = DLGBuildPosition(t,l,b,r)
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "Width", DLGBuildAutoSize() )
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "Height", DLGBuildMatchSize() )
        
        // Appear center-right outside the window
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "X", DLGBuildRelativePosition( "Outside", 1 ) )
        positionTgs.TagGroupSetTagAsTagGroup( "Y", DLGBuildRelativePosition( "Inside", 0 ) )
        DLG.DLGPosition( positionTgs )
        
        self.super.Init( DLG ).Display("Test")
    }
}

image img := RealImage("test",4,100,100)
img.ShowImage()
documentWindow win = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument().ImageDocumentGetWindow()
Alloc(CMyClass).InitAndShow(win)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Actually I'm using a GMS2.3 system, and thus your advices were quite helpful for me. Concerning the difference between GMS1.x, GMS2,x and GMS3.x that you mentioned, I feel it is a troublesome problem. Now Although now I'm writing some handmade library scripts for GMS1.x and GMS2.x (and GMS3.x, if it is possible) systems, it seems that I should prepare different one for these different systems. Thank you again.

Comment: @kachigusa Between GMS 1 and GMS 2 only the commands of registering/Unregistering changed. The other stuff shoud work in both. (And one can use a trick to make code which can register in both versions.)  GMS 3 is different though, because the UI *does no longer have registered palettes* at all. It uses "experiment" panes. The safest way for a script UI working in GMS 3 is to just launch it as modeless dialog.

Comment: But yes, there comes a point where the differences between GMS 1 and GMS 2 and GMS 3 become simply to big to faciliate "all-around-compatibility". GMS 1 is already *very* old. It is a bit like now writing plugins which not only run on Win10 and Win7, but also on 32bit WinXP *and* even Win95....

Comment: Thank you for your additional useful comments. I would like to agree that writing of a script with "all-around-compatibility" is an excessive goal. Under current situation, I feel that my target should be focused to GMS2.x systems (or include GMS1.x systems with small changing of the script).